# Python/Django Code Coverage doesn't cover classmethods

Tags: python, coverage.py, python-coverage

I'm using coverage.py to check the test/code coverage and it seems to consistently skip over any class methods. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Did you call `coverage.start()` before importing your modules? May have not started coverage early enough.

Comment: @DonkeyKong i'm not calling it myself, it's called by django-coverage so I have no idea where it takes place

Comment: You'll have to post some code, and an example of the coverage report demonstrating the problem.  Class methods (or do you mean classmethods?) are supported just fine.

Comment: voting to close: I may have misread what's happening and my tests may be covering more than I thought. I was under the impression that the @classmethods weren't getting tested at all since they didn't appear flagged in the coverage report. thx for the help